# Ubuntu 17.04 Lenovo Yoga 720 Touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, xinput

My touchpad is not detected on my xinput list.

[image]

Is there any resolution to this or am I out of luck? If I'm out of luck, would this be resolved with future versions of Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a live cd for 16.04? Does it work there?

Comment: I booted from a USB for both 16.04 and 17.04 and neither worked.

Comment: Please avoid posting terminal output as a screenshot. Post it as text.  Please [edit] your question and post the output as text. And what are Logitech devices? Are you using some external device?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add it as text--do I have to type it all in or is there an easier way? And the logitech devices are a mouse and keyboard that use a USB receiver. The mouse works and the touchpad still doesn't when they are unplugged.

Comment: Select text in the terminal, right click it and select "Copy", then paste it to your question. Then select the text and press the `{}` button to format it correctly here.

Comment: Is Wacom also an external device? Then it looks like your touchpad doesn't appear at all.

Comment: No, Wacom is the computers touchscreen.

Comment: Is the trackpad dead?

Comment: The trackpad still works on my windows 10 OS, so no

Comment: You have to [install a patched kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397706/install-a-patched-kernel-for-lenovo-yoga-720-15ikb-with-a-working-touchpad)